# How know if Object passed by prop is changed in Vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

How can i know if my object retrivied by props is changed or not?

Example.

I have an object passed by props like:

```
object:{
 id: 1,
 list: [{..},{..}],
 propertyExample: true,
 message: "I know that You will change this input"
}
```

And in my html frontend I have an input that change value of message or another property like:

```
<input type="text" v-model="object.message" />
```

And I would notify when my "entire original object" (that passed by prop) is changed. If I use watch deep the problem As documentation says is:

> Note: when mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array, the
>   old value will be the same as new value because they reference the
>   same Object/Array. Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value.

So I have an object retrieved by props, so I should "disable" save button if object is equals to "original" or "enable" if object is different so if I make an update in frontend like modify property.

so If I enter in a page with my component I have original object like above described, and my **save button** is disabled because the "object" is not changed.

I would enable my save button if I change one of the properties of my object.
so example if I add a object in a property list array described, or if I change property message, or if I add a new property.

Answer (score 0):

Watch function will be called when one of property in props object has been changed.

You can also use "v-bind" to pass all the properties of the object as props:
so

```
<demo v-bind="object"></demo>
```

will be equivalent to

```
<demo :id="object.id" :list="object.list" :propertyExample:"object.propertyExample" :message="object.message"></demo>
```

Then you can watch message prop individually for changes.

**Edit**

You can also use Vue Instance Properties.

> There may be data/utilities you’d like to use in many components, but you don’t want to pollute the global scope. In these cases, you can make them available to each Vue instance by defining them on the prototype:

```
Vue.prototype.$appName = 'My App'
```

Now $appName is available on all Vue instances, even before creation. If we run:

```
new Vue({
  beforeCreate: function () {
    console.log(this.$appName)
  }
})
```

Comment: ok, but if my object has 50 properties that I can't pass one by one by props?

Comment: You don't need to pass all the properties through props. Just pass the whole object as prop using v-bind.

Answer (score 0):

Add watcher to that passed prop. and do something when changed.

```
watch: {
  passedProp(changedObject) {
      //do something...
      change the variable which stands for enabling the "SAVE" button
  }
}
```

OR if you are not using webpack/babel

```
watch: {
      passedProp: function(changedObject) {
          //do something...
          change the variable which stands for enabling the "SAVE" button
      }
    }
```